# The specified field [Report].[Field] could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to create a query where i Join the same table twice, this in order to compare the column value for different rows that belong to the same employee but under different concepts. I've read in a lot of places that giving different "Alias" in each table solve this, however, even when I gave different Alias to each, field the error is still showing.

BTW, I'm relatively new to SQL, I've been digging on videos and pages about how to use it and took some examples from where i built this query.

Here is the code for more refence:

```sql
SELECT [Bonus Calculation.Employee_ID AS EE_ID], [Bonus Calculation.Goal] AS Goals, [Bonus Calculation.Actual%] AS [Actual%]
FROM
    (SELECT [Bonus Calculation.Employee_ID] AS ID1, [Bonus Calculation.Goal] AS G1, [Bonus Calculation.Actual%] AS A1
FROM [Bonus Calculation]
WHERE (([Bonus Calculation].[Goal])='Operating Profit Before Bonus' OR (([Bonus Calculation].[Goal])='Operating Profit After Bonus') OR (([Bonus Calculation].[Goal])='Customer Satisfaction'))) A
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT [Bonus Calculation.Employee_ID] AS ID2, [Bonus Calculation.Goal] AS G2, [Bonus Calculation.Actual%] AS A2
FROM [Bonus Calculation]
WHERE ((([Bonus Calculation].[Goal])='Orders') OR (([Bonus Calculation].[Goal])='Revenue'))) B
ON  A.ID1 = B.ID2
WHERE (
IIF([A.A1]= 0, [B.A2] <=1, [B.A2])
    );
```

Comment: Replace your `[Bonus Calculation.Goal]` and similar with `[Bonus Calculation].[Goal]`.

Comment: Just notice that and, do that for every table/column in the query and is still showing the error

Comment: Obey the error message and prefix those fields with their table name.

Comment: @Gustav Do you mean having them like this?
`SELECT [Bonus Calculation].[Employee_ID] AS bonuscalculation_employeeid, [Bonus Calculation].[Goal] AS bonuscalculation_goal, [Bonus Calculation].[Actual%] AS bonuscalculation_actual` and having a different prefix for each table i want to join?

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    A.ID1 AS EE_ID, 
    A.G1 AS Goals1, 
    B.G2 AS Goals2, 
    A.A1 AS [Actual%1],
    B.A2 AS [Actual%2]
FROM
    (SELECT Employee_ID AS ID1, Goal AS G1, [Actual%] AS A1
    FROM [Bonus Calculation]
    WHERE [Goal] IN ('Operating Profit Before Bonus','Operating Profit After Bonus','Customer Satisfaction')) A
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Employee_ID AS ID2, Goal AS G2, [Actual%] AS A2
    FROM [Bonus Calculation]
    WHERE Goal IN ('Orders','Revenue')) B
    ON  A.ID1 = B.ID2
WHERE 
    IIF([A.A1]= 0, [B.A2] <=1, [B.A2]);
```

Not sure about the WHERE clause, though.